# Why doesn't this jquery form submit work correctly in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

My objective is to open a new window and submit the form on the current page in that window while staying on the same page in the original window. And then, after a slight pause, change the url of the new window. Similar to just posting a form to '_blank' but I want to keep a handle on the new window so I can reload it with a new url.

This works in Chrome and Firefox but not IE (IE11 is what I'm using). In IE, the form submits to the current page instead of the page in the new window. So, it seems setting the target to the new window isn't working in IE. Is this something IE doesn't support? Or do I need to use a different property or syntax?

Ideally the app we're posting to would redirect itself but I can't change that. To make matters worse, it's on a different domain so I don't think iFrames are an option (along with ajax). Correct me if I'm wrong on the iframe solution

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var cacheWin;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var left = window.screenLeft ? window.screenLeft : window.screenX;
        var top = window.screenTop ? window.screenTop : window.screenY;
        //this will happen on page load
        cacheWin = window.open('', 'cacheWin',
                "screenX=" + left + ",screenY=" + top + ",left=" + left + ",top=" + top + ",width=1200,height=800,scrollbars=yes");

        submitForm();
    });

    function submitForm() {
        if (cacheWin) {
            var $mainForm = $('#mainForm');
            $mainForm.prop("target", "cacheWin");
            //submit the form to our new window
            $mainForm.submit();
            cacheWin.focus();
            showResponse(cacheWin);
        } else {
            //wait for a second and try again
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                submitForm();
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    function showResponse(win) {
        //after a delay to allow caching data to submit, show the content
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            displayContents(win);
        }, 1000);
    }

    function displayContents(nwin) {
        nwin.location = '<%=contentUrl%>';
    }
</script>
```

The form:

```
<form id="mainForm" action="<%=cacheAction%>" method="POST">
    .... inputs and some other stuff
</form>
```

Comment: I bet in IE code to submit form never invoked due to error. Check console.

Comment: Ok, so, Why doesn't it work in IE? Where does the logic fail? do some debugging.

Comment: Added explanation of what's not working.

Comment: Would using target="_blank" be acceptable? (no idea on the browser support side of this question)

Comment: @KevinB - See first paragraph... Is there a way to get a 'handle' on the window that's opened using target="_blank" so I can redirect it to a new url?

Comment: shouldn't that be done by the server you are posting to? A workaround would be to post to a hidden iframe, then when it's done (or after a short delay), open a new window with your target url.

Comment: Yeah, ideally the app we're posting to would redirect itself but I can't change that. To make matters worse, it's on a different domain so I don't think iFrames are an option (along with ajax). Correct me if I'm wrong on the iframe solution.